# List all commits affecting a subdirectory in github

Tags: github

Is there a way in GitHub to list all commits that affects a subdirectory (i.e. anyfile or directory in its hierarchy), **without** having to check out the entire repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, you are not looking for the latest change, but all changes made to a folder in a branch. Because latest change is always visible on the grayish bar:

[image: screenshot from github.com showing the latest change to a folder]

All changes made to the folder can be checked by clicking the **History** button right above the area I have circled with red. That ends up at this page: https://github.com/jonasblunck/ccm/commits/master/installation which is filtered for that folder. Compare it with https://github.com/jonasblunck/ccm/commits/master that contains all commits to master.